# Update PHP content every 5s using Ajax or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I'm trying to UPDATE my php page every 5 seconds so the new data can come in into a .json file, so basically what it does, is, it gets the data from the database, and creates a .json file with this data, I need this php file to update every 5 seconds, so the .json file is updating too.
The code (JsonfileAPI.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    function get_data()
    {
        $servername = "nps";
        $dBUsername = "nps";
        $dBPassword = "nps";
        $dBname = "nps";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, 
        $dBname);

        if ($conn->connect_error){
        die ("Connection failed". $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dados;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $json_array = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $json_array[] = array(
                'AutoIncrement'         =>       $row["AutoIncrement"],
                'Aparelho'         =>       $row["aparelho"],
                'Status'         =>       $row["Status"],
            );
        }
        return json_encode($json_array);
    }
    $file_name = 'dadosjson' . '.json';

    if (file_put_contents($file_name, get_data()))
    {
        echo $file_name. ' file created';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'There is some error';
    }
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "JsonfileAPI.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $('.time').html(response);
        }
    });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your application, I suggest to use separate files like index.php (for your html code) and action.php for PHP script. and don`t need .json file.

Try this, in index.php html part and javascript part like this

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                type: 'post',
              //  dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
                  $('.time').html(response);
              }
            });
        }, 5000);
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="time">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your action.php file should be like this,

```
  <?php
    $localhost = "nps";
    $username = "nps";
    $password = "nps";
    $dbname = "nps";

    // db connection
    $connect = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // check connection
    if ($connect->connect_error) {
      die("Connection Failed : " . $connect->connect_error);
    } else {
     //  echo "Successfully connected".$dbname;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dados";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);

    $output = array('data' => array());

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $output['data'][] = array(
      $row[0],
      $row[1],
      $row[2]
     );
    }
   }
   $connect->close();

   echo json_encode($output);
```

I have checked and it work fine. Think it will be help.

Comment: hey, thx for the help, But I was doing a separte .json file because I'm reading the info from the .json file with a ESP32, and I make a get request for that, will it still work with this code? And should I put the javascript inside the index.php?

Comment: For some reason my action.php is not updating, gonna update question, so you can see

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF I assum the process is get data from database and then show in html in every 5 seconds with updating. is n`t it?

Comment: What it is supposed to do, Its update the info from my database every 5s, Without refreshing the page every time, The data that It gets as the response has to be as a JSON format so I can read with my ESP32, I was having problems with JSON format inside a php sketch, because when I do the GET Command it doesnt read the JSON array correctly, that why I made a .json file

Comment: In your javascript code of index.php file post a request every 5 second into action.php file, then response json data into your index.php and you can get into html

Comment: If you show the data in the action.php will be better

Comment: Can you make the action.php update every 5s instead of the index.php?

Comment: if you want to get data as json type only tou should change type into json (uncomment my code line type :json in javascript)

Comment: I'm not getting any reponse from the index.php, and the action.php doesn't update at all =(

Comment: see your console

Comment: This is what I get, my index.php is called main3.php by the way. Erro = Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main3.php:11

Comment: is telling that the erro is here: $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212832/discussion-between-lakmal-bodhinayaka-and-nilton-schumacher-f).